# str = str.split(",") AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' building a client for an online game running into this error

Tags: python, attributeerror, nonetype, strsplit

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.rect = (x,y,width,height)
        self.vel = 3

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, self.rect)

    def move(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.x -= self.vel

        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.x += self.vel

        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.y -= self.vel

        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.y += self.vel

        self.update()

    def update(self):
        self.rect = (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)

def read_pos(str):
    str = str.split(",")
    return int(str[0]), int(str[1])

def make_pos(tup):
    return str(tup[0]) + "," + str(tup[1])

def redrawWindow(win, player, player2):
    win.fill((255,255,255))
    player.draw(win)
    player2.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: What is your question about this error? Why do you call split on something that is None?

Comment: I'm sending information from the client to my server about the position of the players and it's returning this error, I'm not sure why this happening

Comment: It's happening because `read_pos` gets called with `None` as argument.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.